# Тире при обособлении приложения

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение.

*Русский язык в совершенстве знает только один человек - Дитмар Розенталь.*

Есть же правило, говорящее, что обособление приложения на конце выделяется не запятой, а тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно, по правилам такое обособление возможно. Но это не значит, что в конце предложения  приложение всегда отделяется тире.
См.например: <... >двумя крыльями дворца Ирода Великого вышел прокуратор Иудеи *Понтий Пилат* 
В конце предложения приложение отделяется тире, когда ему в высказывании придается большое значение.
Но на лице Елены в три часа дня стрелки показывали самый низкий и угнетенный час жизни - ***половину шестого*** (М. Булгаков). 
Подходил к концу август -  ***последний месяц лета.***

Comment: А вот такое вот предложение... 

"Работаю как модератор в Facebook - в самой лучшей социальной сети". Можно же ведь использовать тире?

Comment: Однозначно!

Comment: Ловите награду! :)

Answer (score 2):

(1) Русский язык в совершЕнстве (пауза) знал только одИн человек (увеличенная пауза) – Дитмар Розенталь. "Вариант с запятой кажется сомнительным, так как слова «только один» увеличивают паузу".

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Такой вариант не только кажется сомнительным, он просто невозможен.

А почему «только один» увеличивает паузу"? Это можно объяснить вполне корректно с помощью структурного анализа. А структурный анализ говорит нам о том, что на слове ОДИН, требующим пояснения, мы делаем логическое ударение, при этом на это же слово смещается тоническое ударение. А такое смещенное ударение делает увеличение паузы неизбежным, что на письме соответствует знаку тире.

(2)Русский язык в совершенстве (пауза)  знал мой учИтель (пауза), Дитмар Розенталь.  Здесь похожая структура, но нет смещения тонического ударения, поэтому пауза только слегка намечена, обособление обозначается запятой.

(3) Русский язык в совершЕнстве (пауза) знал мой учитель Дитмар РозентАль. Это простое предложение без обособления, состоящее из двух фраз.

Выводы:

1) Предложение (1) обособляется в обязательном порядке с помощью тире. Варианты (2) и (3) автор выбирает по своему усмотрению.

2) Деление существительных на собственные и нарицательные важно только при выборе раздельной формы написания приложений. Но если мы выбираем для обособления запятую или тире, то здесь важна только структура предложения.

Сравнить:
(1)Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу.(2)Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, владельцу небольшого имения. При одинаковой структуре предложения становится неважным, чем выражено приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Тут накладываются 2 правила:

1.**Приложения – имена собственные**, если они имеют пояснительный оттенок значения (можно вставить *а именно, то есть, а зовут его*),  выделяются, как и любое пояснение, запятой или тире.

Е*лизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу.*

У *дверей, на солнышке, зажмурившись, лежала любимая борзая собака отца — Милка.*

2.Правило о **тире перед приложением в конце предложения** формально не относится к именам собственным (они вынесены в отдельное правило). Но 1-е основание у такого тире то же:

1) **пояснительный оттенок значения** (*Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину*),

2) **оттенок самостоятельности приложения**; такие приложения часто содержат развернутую характеристику предмета или лица (*Приближалась ночь — самое удобное для партизан время*).

То есть приложения – имена собственные могут отделяться **запятой или тире**. При этом надо учитывать длину паузы. В нашем случае предпочтительно:

*Русский язык в совершенстве знаЛ только один человек – Дитмар Розенталь.*

Вариант с запятой кажется сомнительным, так как слова «только один» увеличивают паузу.

Ср.: *Русский язык в совершенстве знал мой учитель, Дитмар Розенталь.*

*Русский язык в совершенстве знал мой учитель Дитмар Розенталь* (без пояснительной интонации).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Часто возникает путаница. Человек думает, что если после *а именно* перед однородными членами ставится двоеточие, то его можно поставить после любого *а именно*, даже подразумеваемого. Так возникают ошибки:

*Иногда что-нибудь хочется сделать, а именно: почитать* (ошибка перед пояснительным членом предложения).

*Русский язык в совершенстве знал только один человек: Дитмар Розенталь* (ошибка перед приложением).